# Failed make when installing madplay source

Tags: software-installation, source, ld

I am attempting to get madplay installed on my shared host

I've run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME CPPFLAGS="-I /home/dir/include" LDFLAGS="-L /home/dir/lib"
```

and then "make", but on that on run into an error I can't understand:

```
/home/dir/lib: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [madplay] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/madplay-0.15.2b'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/madplay-0.15.2b'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please, point out to me why it is looking for a directory instead of a file? This is preventing me from installing this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave out the space between `-L` and `/home/dir/lib` in the
`LDFLAGS` setting. As it is the compiler assumes that `-L` has no argument and `/home/dir/lib` is a source file.

You should probably also remove the space after  the -I option, as per the directives for [gcc options directory search](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).